# Visual Studio 2013 debug not stepping in

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a web application on Visual Studio 2013. On older versions, whenever there is a bug in the web app, I moved from the browser to the visual studio to the line where the code is.

Now, whenever there is a bug, I just see it in the browser without being able to see it in the Visual Studio. As if the debugger is not able to step into my code.

This has been going on for all my web projects which makes me feel that it is a setting in VS but I am not able to locate it.

can anyone help?

Comment: If you create a new web application, are you able to debug it? If yes, then check in your web.config if debugging set to true.

Comment: My debug is enabled. Also, I have created a new web app now with a simple code that should throw and error. I got the yellow error screen on the page, but I was not taken first to visual studio as expected :( ..

Comment: Did you try these [MSDN steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes. Both are set properly. the ASP.NET debugging in the project properties and the debug in web.config

Comment: Did you see <customErrors> tag in web.config and what its mode is set to? set it to "Off" and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out what was wrong here.

it seems that for some reason, under Debug in the main menu and under Exceptions, nothing was checked! I checked ALL "Common Language Run-time Exceptions" and it worked for me.

However, you need to spend sometime there in the debugging list. If you enable ALL, you will get all sort of exceptions captured.